# Google ML Kit metrics upload details/communication protocol

Tags: google-mlkit

In the Google ML Kit web documentation it discusses that usage metrics will be uploaded but does not give a lot of detail: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms#privacy

Does anyknow know (or know a contact) as to whether the metrics upload uses an HTTPS protocol? Also if someone knows more details about the metrics that are uploaded.

Comment: Can you clarify what other details you would like to see?

Comment: Thanks!  Here is an example of what I was thinking of with regard to more details.. basically some enumeration of the data that is collected:

https://help.uplandsoftware.com/localytics/help/_SettingsSystem/User%20privacy.htm#Data. 

https://help.uplandsoftware.com/localytics/help/_Analytics/How%20Localytics%20understands%20data.htm#Dimensio

Comment: Thanks, we'll see if we can expand a bit on the information there. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Sorry for the delay here, we have updated our Terms & Privacy page, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

PM for ML Kit here. Correct, the metrics are encrypted in transit using SSL (Https). We'll add this clarification to the privacy page.